# Can not build ios app into device because "embedded framework 'SharedCode.framework' was built for iOS Simulator."

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-native

I use Kotlin Native (multiplatform) and I have create a TestKotinNative app, but only work when run on simulator.
When I run on my device (iphone 7, 13.4.1), xcode show error "TestKotlinNative.xcodeproj Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'SharedCode.framework' was built for iOS Simulator."
My Xcode version: 11.4.1
Please help me! Thank

This is my build.gradle.kts (same with https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/06_SettingUpKotlinFramework)

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
    //select iOS target platform depending on the Xcode environment variables
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "SharedCode"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("android")

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
    }

    sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
    }

}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

    /// selecting the right configuration for the iOS
    /// framework depending on the environment
    /// variables set by Xcode build
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val framework = kotlin.targets
        .getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios")
        .binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)

    /// generate a helpful ./gradlew wrapper with embedded Java path
    doLast {
        val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
        gradlew.writeText("#!/bin/bash\n"
                + "export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\n"
                + "cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n"
                + "./gradlew \$@\n")
        gradlew.setExecutable(true)
    }
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv5iO.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

A dirty way to keep using the new versions of xCode with Kotlin multiplatform framework is...
Before change the platform (simulator and iphone) to run your project just go in frameworks location and delete the framework file. XCode will re-built your framework and app will deploy on your choosen platform

Comment: At the moment this is indeed the easiest workaround. Some additional info can be found in the Kotlin bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40907.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you declare the `iOSTarget` variable to be always set for `iosX64` target, which is a simulator. In the hands-on example, the idea was to choose targets depending on the Xcode build settings. but in your code, this part is commented leaving the only simulator set by default. Try fixing it to be exactly as in the hands-on final version(see it [here](https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/mpp-ios-android/blob/step-008/SharedCode/build.gradle.kts))

Comment: yes, I use like commend
```
//        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
//            ::iosArm64
//        else
//            ::iosX64
```
but not work. so I try hard ::iosX64 or ::iosArm64, it work for simulator or device
when use "if else" build alway fail

Comment: What do you mean by "build always fail"? If you set an iosArm64 and start building for the device, does it work correctly?

Comment: This is wrong, the hands on example no longer works as of XCode 11.4, XCode will fail to build the app regardless of the initial check.

Comment: Hi, @theolll! Can you please tell some more on Xcode 11.4 incompatibility here? I'm hearing it for the first time, and this problem seems to be a serious one.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev yes sure, in order to reproduce this you can simply clone the hands on final repo (https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/mpp-ios-android) and then: Run packForXcode once in Android Studio, Switch over to XCode and build and run on the simulator, verify this works, Plug in a physical iOS device and press build and run again, verify this fails.

In my project I'm using a shell script that I run manually when switching between devices or building for the app store. From the research I did I saw that the Flutter team had the same issue and managed a fix.

Comment: When I tried to run on an iPhone device , I also got "
...  'SharedCode.framework' was built for iOS Simulator." I deleted the '/SharedCode.framework' directory and Xcode built the framework again. My Xcode is 11.5.

Comment: Is there a way to build the xcframework so that it contains both, simulator AND device?

Comment: Hello, @Georg! Right now, XCFrameworks are not supported out-of-the-box, but there is work being done to support them(see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42667). As a different option, you can declare bot simulator and device targets, and make a fat framework as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#build-universal-frameworks).